# Listar e exibir imagens na storage do laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, image

Desenvolvo uma aplicação com Laravel 5.3, onde o `_DocumentRoot_` fica na pasta `public`. Imagens de upload ficam em `storage/app/public`, porém não sei como listar estas imagens em uma `view`, somente consigo exibi-las diretamente através do `response()` do Laravel.

Obs.: os nomes das imagens estão salvos no banco de dados.

Se eu usar `return response()->file('caminho_da_imagem')` na `view` ou no `controller` ele me retorna a imagem em um background escuro;

Tentei também usar o Intervetion Image com `Image::make('caminho_da_imagem')->response();`, mas o resultado foi o mesmo.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Você tem algum código do que está tentando fazer?

Comment: Atualizado! Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já fiz algo assim da seguinte forma:

1. No controller, responsável pela view das imagens, eu resgato do banco de dados os paths de todas as imagens que eu quero exibir.
2. Envio este array para a view.
3. Na view, para cada elemento do array, crio uma tag img com o caminho informado.

**Em termos de código...**

No controller

```
$fotos = Imagem::where('album_id', album_id)->get()->pluck('path');
```

Retornando

```
return view('nome.da.view')->with([
    'fotos' => $fotos
]);
```

Na view

```
@if( count($fotos)>0 )
    @foreach( $fotos as $foto )
        <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$foto) }}">
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Bom, essa foi a solução que eu encontrei e funcionou. Sou apenas um iniciante em Laravel e estou compartilhando minha experiência. Espero ter ajudado.

**Obs: O código pode ser diferente para você mas a lógica continua a mesma.**

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, mas estou usando a pasta padrão para upload do Laravel => `storage` subpastas `app/public`. E não a pasta `public` subpasta `storage`.

Comment: Eu linkei a storage e deu certo do jeito que vc falou. Obrigado

Comment: Boa, eu tinha me esquecido de citar o link de pastas. Desculpa!

Answer (score 1):

então o seu problema pode ser resolvido da seguinte forma.
Crie uma rota la em routes/web por exemplo :'storage/fotos/{filename}' , "controller@exeplofotos")->name(exemplo.fotos)

No controller:
public function exemplofotos($parametro)
{
try {
$fotos = SeuArquivoDeModel::select('campocomoarquivo')
->where('campocomoarquivo',$parametro)
->get();
foreach ($fotos as $key =>$foto) {
$arq = $foto['campocomoarquivo'];
}
return response()
->file(storage_path("app/public/arquivo/$arq"));

```
              } catch (\Exception $e) {
        
                return view('notfound');
              }
```

}

Basicamente o que está rolando ai é que você irá criar uma rota  referenciando um controller e nesse controller haverá um método que vai te retonrar sua foto ja exibindo ela, ou seja, vai possibilitar que você acesse aquele arquivo que está dentro da pasta storage/app/public.

Na view é só você acessar a rota na tag src com o arquivo como parâmetro.
arquivo)}}" alt="">

Neste caso eu tenho um array de dados então eu seleciono varias fotos de uma vez, uma solução particular seria